# How to test the current text of a Tkinter text box widget before inserting new text after user clicks on a button?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, insert

What I am trying to do is to attach files in an email form constructed using the Tkinter module.  It currently works with one, but...
What if I want to attach multiple files?

I created a button where the user can browse for the files and it will write the path of the selected file into the text box.
Here's where I run into an issue...
If the text box is empty, I do not want to insert a semicolon before the filepath.

`.get` and `.index` will not work in this situation.  It doesn't matter where these lines are located.  They always return the final result instead of the current one...  Therefore, the result is always False (the text box is not blank) and will insert the semicolon.

I've read somewhere that I'd need to bind it first.  I tried reading the documentation on it, but no relevant examples...

The issue is within `def browse`.

```
from tkinter import filedialog, \
    Tk, Label, Button, Text, \
    RIGHT, LEFT, END, W
from os import path


class EmailPopup:
    def __init__(self, from_address=None, recipients=None, subject=None, body=None, salutation=None,
                 password=None, attachment=None):
        self.master = Tk()
        master = self.master

        self.master.title = master.title("Compose New Email")

        self.from_label = Label(master, text="FROM: ")
        self.from_label.pack(anchor=W, padx=4)
        self.from_address_entry = Text(master, height=1, width=75)  # Resist the temptation to combine these lines.
        if from_address:  # They will not work as expected when using get().
            self.from_address_entry.insert(END, from_address)  # <- will error if None (tkinter.TclError)
        self.from_address_entry.pack(anchor=W, padx=4)

        self.to_label = Label(master, text="TO: ")
        self.to_label.pack(anchor=W, padx=4)
        self.recipients_entry = Text(master, height=1, width=75)
        if recipients:
            self.recipients_entry.insert(END, recipients)
        self.recipients_entry.pack(anchor=W, padx=4)

        self.subject_label = Label(master, text="SUBJECT: ")
        self.subject_label.pack(anchor=W, padx=4)
        self.subject_entry = Text(master, height=1, width=75)
        if subject:
            self.subject_entry.insert(END, subject)
        self.subject_entry.pack(anchor=W, padx=4)

        self.body_label = Label(master, text="BODY: ")
        self.body_label.pack(anchor=W, padx=4)
        text = Text(master, height=25, width=75)

        if body:
            text.insert(END, body)
        if salutation:
            text.insert(END, salutation + "\n")

        self.body_entry = text

        self.body_entry.pack(anchor=W, padx=4)

        self.attachment_label = Label(master, text="Attachment: (type full path to file)")
        self.attachment_label.pack(anchor=W, padx=4)
        self.attachment_link = Text(master, height=1, width=75)
        if attachment:
            self.attachment_link.insert(END, path.abspath(attachment))
        self.attachment_link.config(fg='blue')
        self.attachment_link.pack(anchor=W, padx=4)

        Button(master, text='BROWSE FOR FILE', command=self.browse).pack(anchor=W, padx=4)
        Button(master, text='SEND', command=self.send, fg="green").pack(side=LEFT, padx=4, pady=8)
        Button(master, text='CANCEL', command=self.quit, fg="red").pack(side=RIGHT, padx=4)

        self.password = password

        self.from_address_entry.bind("<Tab>", self.callback)
        self.recipients_entry.bind("<Tab>", self.callback)
        self.subject_entry.bind("<Tab>", self.callback)
        self.body_entry.bind("<Tab>", self.callback)
        self.attachment_link.bind("<Tab>", self.callback)

        master.mainloop()

    def callback(self, event):
        event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
        return "break"

    def browse(self):

        browser_window = self.master
        browser_window.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file to attach")
        result = browser_window.filename

# THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS:
        if result:
            if self.attachment_link.index("end") == 0:
                self.attachment_link.insert(END, result)
            else:
                self.attachment_link.insert(END, "; " + result)

            # This isn't working as expected either...
            # if self.attachment_link.get('1.0', 'end') is None:  <--- Getting False even when blank
            #    self.attachment_link.insert(END, result)
            # else:
            #    self.attachment_link.insert(END, ";" + result)

    def quit(self):
        self.master.quit()
        exit(0)

    def send(self):
        self.master.quit()


EmailPopup()
```

Expected that `.get` or `.index` would return a `None` or blank.
Actual result is that it gives me the final result with a semicolon `"; C:/Google Drive/Processed Jobs/"` instead of current.
Result should've been `"C:/Google Drive/Processed Jobs/"`.
So it's firing all out of order and is super-confusing.

Comment: You haven't provided an [mcve], so I can't run your code. However, I believe the problem is that `self.attachment_link.index("end")` will _never_ return `0` as a result — so the `else` clause always executes.

Comment: `get(...)` will _never_ return `None`. You need to check for an empty string.

Comment: @martineau You should be able to run my code now.  It would attempt to look for a couple of pictures that wouldn't exist on your computer and error.  I whittled it down to only what is needed.

Comment: @Bryan: It wouldn't ever return `None`, but comparing it to the empty string isn't a solution because it doesn't return that when the Text widget is empty either (it returns `"2.0"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, technically, your question is a duplicate of [tkinter - check if Text widget is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539617/tkinter-check-if-text-widget-is-empty), but I can't mark it as such because the OP of that question never accepted an answer — so I'll repeat the first part of what's in @Bryan Oakley's answer to it here since it's correct (and should have been accepted).

> Tkinter automatically adds a newline at the end of the data in the widget. To see if the widget is empty, compare the index right before this newline with the starting index; if they are the same, the widget is empty.

This implies that you could do what you want by changing this portion of your code:

```
# THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS:
        if result:
#            if self.attachment_link.index("end") == 0::
            if self.attachment_link.index("end-1c") == '1.0':  # First attachment?
                self.attachment_link.insert(END, result)
            else:
                self.attachment_link.insert(END, '; ' + result)
```

Note that the `Text` widget's `index()` method [always returns a string](http://web.archive.org/web/20190201161306id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html) in [this format](http://web.archive.org/web/20190212094653id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-index.html), which is why checking for it being equal to `None` or the integer `0` would likely *never* be the correct thing to do…

Comment: I like how it accomplishes what I'm wanting by changing 1 line.  That's a lot simpler than counting keys...  Thank you.

Comment: @Austin: Yeah, it's nice when it works out like that. Note: You could also use `if self.attachment_link.index("end") == "2.0":` since the end of an "empty" `Text` widget is also the beginning of the second line (because of the automatically added newline).

Answer (score -1):

This is my current solution.  I decided to bind the attachment text box to a new function that counts the keys.  Then, if that number is greater than zero, the program will add the semicolon.  If you can think of a better approach, then please let me know...

```
self.attachment_link.bind("<Key>", self.callback_attachments_entry)

        self.key_count = 0


    def callback_attachments_entry(self, event):
        print(repr(event.char))
        if event.char == '\x08' and self.key_count != 0:  # backspace
            self.key_count -= 1
        else:
            self.key_count += 1

    def browse(self):
        browser_window = self.master
        browser_window.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file to attach")
        result = browser_window.filename
        if result:
            if self.key_count > 0:
                result = "; " + result
            self.attachment_link.insert(END, result)
            self.attachment_link.insert(END, result)
            self.key_count += len(result)
```